# Open PWA link in new window using manifest display settings

Tags: javascript, progressive-web-apps, manifest.json

I created a PWA application.  The PWA manifest "display" is set to "minimal-ui".  It looks great.

I have a pricelist integrated into the app.  When user clicks the pricelist button it opens a new window.  The new window opens in chrome instead of "minimal-ui".  There is an option in in the chrome address bar on the far right to "open with" the application which then closes chrome and opens the pricelist page with the "minimal-ui" display settings.

I want to avoid the manual step so the pricelist opens directly with the "minimal-ui" display.

I cannot find an answer on stack or google to accomplish this.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

```js
const NEW_WINDOW = window.open('./pages/pricelist/pricelist.html', '_blank')
        NEW_WINDOW.open
```

Comment: Up vote as this seems a useful question. From similar questions, it appears to depend on how the window is opened.  So sharing the button code would probably be helpful.

Comment: The word `integrated` rings an alarm bell to me - in what way is this "price list" *integrated*?

Comment: @JaromandaX the "pricelist" is stored in local storage and the application is 100% client side (PWA) for now.  The employees need a way to search data and create quotes offline.  It's an internal application and can only be accessed on a company computer via a company server.  I am curious what is ringing an alarm bell for you?

Comment: Not sure @Let'sApp - thought it was like a document or something - but from the description in the comment, you're storing data in local storage so, no alarm bells :p curious as to why you open a new window though, and how you are doing it - it's hard to help with zero code though

Comment: @JaromandaX updated post with code.  I've tried many variations but  whenever new page is opened it is opened in the browser not in a new window with the settings specified in the manifest.  You'd think something so simple and basic would be supported or would be tons of information on.

Comment: I want to do something similar but they are different questions.  I think the answer to this question will also provide me with the answer to my question. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75563889/how-can-i-make-a-button-which-opens-a-new-instance-of-my-web-app   
someone please help.

Comment: I believe that the answer most likely lies in serviceWorker.js code But I am lost as to how to implement this.